# Uniform distribution on $\{\frac{i}{n}: 1 \leq i \leq n \}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to do a problem in which there is a type of distribution I am not familiar with, the exercise says: Find the limit in distribution of the sequence $(Z_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, where for each $n$, the random variable $Z_n$ has uniform distribution in the set $\{\frac{i}{n}: 1 \leq i \leq n \}$

So, for a given $t$, what is the cumulative function $F_{Z_n}(t)$?

I would appreciate if someone could clear this up for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$F_{Z_n}(t)=Pr(Z_n \leq t)=\begin{cases}0 & ,t\leq 0 \\ \frac{\lfloor tn \rfloor}{n} &, 0 \leq t \leq 1 \\1 &, t \geq 1\end{cases}$$

When $t \in (0,1)$, we need to count how many $i \in \left\{1, \ldots, n\right\}$ that satisfy $\frac{i}{n}\leq t$, that is $i \leq nt$ and $i$ is an integer. Clearly, the answer is $\lfloor tn \rfloor$. Hence the probability is $\frac{\lfloor tn \rfloor}{n}$.